# is there any extra latency using an amp sim on wine?

Tags: sound, wine, ubuntu-studio

I want to use AmpliTube amp sim on ubuntu studio but there isn't a linux version for it, can I just use wine and will it have any extra latency? if so how much latency?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, however consider giving the Guitarix program a try. It is an GNU virtual guitar amp that is open source and native to Linux. I believe it sounds comparable to my D!g!t#c% pedalboard. I have achieved latency as low as 6ms with it.

To install guitarix in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install guitarix
```

Comment: I don't really like the UI on guitarix, but I'll make sure to try it.
I have gotten 4ms latency with amplitube but I have no checking of that other than a program on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

To find if a Windows app has been tested for WINE, visit https://appdb.winehq.org/ and search for your app. Latency information for WINE apps is not tracked here on this website.

Answer (score 0):

There is NO extra latency when using Amplitube on Linux thru' wine.

However, check out https://tonelib.net/gfx-overview/ <- Cheap license, only nagscreen until you pay, great great sounds (not opensource though). Interface isn't as polished as Amplitube, but it's far easier to use for it.

I tried "guitarix" - I was not too happy with it I must admit